# IntelliJ: running the main method on mac OS Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I recently got myself a mac and I'm really confused at why my IntelliJ does not seem to have an option to "Run" the main method that is sitting in my Application.java. I'm just trying to run a basic example.

On Windows, I normally I just right click on the Application.java file and select "Run Application.main()" and then it runs but on my mac version of IntelliJ there is no such option:

[image: run main method]

Then I try to set the config by clicking "Edit Configuration":

[image: edit config]

[image: edit config]

And then I tried to set my Main class as "Application.java" but it does not let me click "OK".

[image: choose main class]

I'm using java 1.8 to compile:

[image: java]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your project is not correctly imported,
and IntelliJ doesn't treat your source code as source code.

In your first screenshot, in the view of the project's directory,
I see that all these directories have the same brown color:

```
java
  com
    futureprocessing
      ...
```

When a project is correctly imported,
the `java` directory should look green,
and the sub-directories under should be shown in dotted notation,
so for example `com.futureprocessing...`.

It looks like your project is a Gradle project.
Try to right-click on `build.gradle` and select reimport.
Or you might reimport from scratch.
This assumes that `build.gradle` is correctly written,
and that you are able to build your project on the command line.
Only in that case, IntelliJ should be able to import or re-import it correctly.

If importing/reimporting doesn't work reasonably (though it really should),
then you can try the tips in the answer and mark the source and resources directories manually to be treated as such.

Comment: Thanks - eventually, I redownloaded my code from github and then instead of importing the code into intelliJ, I open the code and it seemed to have worked. I might have also not set up my environmental variables correctly as this is a new machine only purchased yesterday so that could have also contributed to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `java` directory is not marked as a *Sources root*. Right click the `java` directory in project view and select *Mark As/Sources Root*.

Similarly the `resources` directory is not marked as *Resources root*. You can mark it as such the same way.

These problems are probably caused by incorrectly importing the project and so on. So other solution might be to try to import the project again if it doesn't work.